# Force static route for IP on same subnet?

Tags: route

Any way to force the use of a defined host static route when the IP is on the same subnet and disregards the static route entry?

For instance I have a host host:
192.168.1.2 with subnet 255.255.255.0 and a default of 192.168.1.1

I'd like to communicate with 192.168.1.3 via 192.168.1.102.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the entry to the routing table:

***Windows***

```
route add 192.168.1.3 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.102
```

***Linux***

```
route add -host 192.168.1.3 gw 192.168.1.102
```

*However*, you will likely have an asymmetric routing condition when return traffic from 192.168.1.3 returns to your 192.168.1.2 host.  That return traffic, unless otherwise configured with a similarly mirrored route, will be directly delivered.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Windows? Linux? AIX?

For Windows, this command works fine:

`route add 192.168.1.3 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.102`

Even if you're inside the `192.168.1.0/24` network, it will attempt to route. I can't vouch for behaviour on other OS's.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, the route to the destination is localy changeable. The way back isn't this way. The reply packets will arrive you direct from host 192.168.1.3. Next, you must make sure. that 192.168.1.102 will forward packages.